# SQL Server : grabbing DISTINCT column and the rest

Tags: sql, sql-server

Supposed I want to select the distinct Email column but I also want the other columns in that row to be stored in my object. This is what I got

```
SELECT DISTINCT NLMember2.Email
INTO holddups99
FROM NLMember2, holdkey0
WHERE NLMember2.Email = holdkey0.Email
```

The above query works, however it only stores the Email columns. I want to store all columns with the DISTINCT email condition.

I have been stuck for a while now.

Cheers

EDITED

To clarify a little further I got ID,Email,Name,Address, ..... in NLMember2
I only want to store the duplicate Emails into holddups99 but with it's other columns too i.e. ID, Name, Address,..... from NLMember2

Comment: What are the other columns? If there are 3 records with the same `Email` then from which record do you want to take the rest of the values?

Comment: If you only want to distinct on the email column, then you'll need decide what to do with the other (possible) duplicate columns and then select them out in some manner

Comment: What you're trying to do is a logic flaw. You can't pull distinct values of one column, and then accompanying values. What should be returned for those other values? The first result? The maximum result?

Comment: @OGHaza from NLMember2

Comment: @A.Mo Imagine you have 2 records (Name, Email) in NL2Member (Adrian Mo, a.mo@email.com) and (Alex Mo, a.mo@email.com). When you SELECT DISTINCT Email you get 1 value a.mo@email.com. Now which name do you expect the query to retrieve for you, Alex Mo or Adrian Mo. We don't know what you expect the result to be, which is why we can't answer your question.

Comment: @OGHaza it doesn't matter either one will do, as long as there's only 1 a.mo@email.com  Thanks

Comment: I would imagine Tim's answer below will do what you want then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to group by `Email`, but then you need to tell us how you want to aggregate the other columns that are not part of the group by clause. You could take the lowest(MIN) or highest(MAX) values or whatever.

Another approach is  using `ROW_NUMBER` in a CTE, i pick only the first row of each email-group:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT nl.Email, OtherColumns, ... ,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Email ORDER BY Email ASC)
    FROM dbo.NLMember2 nl INNER JOIN dbo.holdkey0 hk
        ON nl.Email = hk.Email 
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1
```

Modify the order by in the `ROW_NUMBER` to change the logic which row you want to take.